# minimization problem with complex constraints

Tags: optimization, statistical-inference

I have to minimize

$ |\mathrm{log}(1-\alpha_1) - \mathrm{log}(\alpha_2)|$

my constraints is $\alpha_1 +\alpha_2 = \alpha$ and $0<\alpha<1$

this is related to finding optimal confidence interval in statistical inference subject my background is statistics so I am very weak in math so please understand my dumb question. but I was wondering if someone could enlighten me with this problem.

edit: actually $ \mathrm{log}(1-\alpha_1) - \mathrm{log}(\alpha_2)$ is the distance so probably I will have minimize the absolute value?

Comment: Is $\alpha$ a variable or is it a fixed parameter?

Comment: $\alpha$ is variable so the $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ can be function of $\alpha$ but I think it's okay to fix $\alpha$ let's say 0.05

Comment: In mathematics it is advisable to say "complicated" instead of "complex" unless you are actually talking about things involving complex numbers.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is fixed then set $\alpha_2=\alpha-\alpha_1$ and forget about the constraint.